# Tampermonkey match all subdirectories

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome, match, tampermonkey

I am using Tampermonkey to run a script on every page of the form:

https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/csc413-2020-01/assignments/2/submissions/329/results/329/edit

where the general structure is

https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/csc413-2020-01/assignments/2/submissions/#NUM/results/#NUM/edit

I am trying to match this URL via: 
`https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/csc413-2020-01/assignments/2/*`, but the script is not triggering with this template.

The full script is below:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         CSC413 autoscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Automation
// @author       II
// @match https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/csc413-2020-01/assignments/2/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';
    console.log("script running");
    //code here
    console.log("finished execution");
})();
```

Does anyone know what is going on here? It matches if I use the generic 
`@include https://*/*`

Comment: On my end, when I go to that link, I get redirected to `https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/csc413-2020-01/?locale=en`. Does that occur for you as well? (maybe need `locale=en` in the match, to start with?)

Comment: Redirect is probably shown only for unsigned users. The actual problem is likely that the site is a modern AJAX-driven SPA so you should match the entire host `https://markus.teach.cs.toronto.edu/*` and observe URL changes (by overriding `pushState` and listening to `popstate`) or observe DOM changes (periodically or via MuattionObserver). There should be answers that show these solutions in detail.

Comment: Thanks both of you, yes @wOxxOm the redirect disappears once you authenticate. Your suggestion works, but I'm still curious as to why we observe this behaviour. Even if it is an AJAX SPA with dynamic URL routing, we should still be able to inspect and match the url; for instance `window.location.href` returns the URL as specified by the tampermonkey script

Comment: No, userscripts are only injected when the page environment is created for the first time. As for dynamic navigation via History API it doesn't change the page environment.

Comment: Thanks for all the insight. The site is a React app, so it makes sense that the page environment is not ready, and what we are actually seeing is the History API at work here. Furthermore, it seems like since React has a shadow DOM, any tampermonkey/client-side scripting will be a pain so I'll probably stop working on this for now

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape slashes and dots, because they have a special meaning in regex. 
and you need to add a dot before the star. The dot means ANY ONE character. The star quantifies it saying "zero or more" of those. `.*` mathes everything. In your code you write `/*`. which says "zero or more slashes"

```
https:\/\/markus\.teach\.cs\.toronto\.edu\/csc413-2020-01\/assignments\/2\/.*
```

Demo
https://regex101.com/r/CRtpWT/1